# Не добавляется фото в базу данных Firebase Android

Tags: java, android, база-данных, firebase

Я создал регистрацию юзера через страницы. Он заполняет на каждой странице что-то из личных данных и это передается через intent в некст активити. В активити с добавлением фото я создаю объект юзера и закидываю в бд. Но проблема в том, что закидывается все, кроме саомого фото

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_photo);

    Intent givenIntent = getIntent();   //Intent предыдущего класса
    User user = givenIntent.getParcelableExtra("user");

    assert user != null;
    user.setPermissions(Permissions.SIMPLE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterPhotoActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    registrationNextButton = findViewById(R.id.registrationNextBtn);
    addPhotosImageButton = findViewById(R.id.registerPhotoImgBtn);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    userImagesStorageReference = storage.getReference().child("users_images");

    addPhotosImageButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        chooseImage();
    });

    registrationNextButton.setOnClickListener(v ->  {
        String mail = user.getMail();
        String password = user.getPassword();
        createAndAddUser(mail, password, user);
    });
}

private void createAndAddUser(String email, String password, User addUser) {
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "createUserWithEmail:success");
                    FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
                    assert user != null;
                    addUser.setID(user.getUid().toString());
                    addUser.setMainPhoto(photoPath);
                    databaseReference.push().setValue(addUser);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterPhotoActivity.this, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.w("TAG", "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                }
            });
}

private void chooseImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Выберите изображение"), RC_IMAGE_PICKER);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_IMAGE_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        assert data != null;
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

        assert selectedImageUri != null;
        StorageReference imageRef = userImagesStorageReference.child(Objects.requireNonNull(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment()));

        UploadTask uploadTask = imageRef.putFile(selectedImageUri);

        Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(task -> {
            if (!task.isSuccessful())
                throw Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException());
            return imageRef.getDownloadUrl();
        }).addOnCompleteListener(task1 ->  {
            if (task1.isSuccessful()) {
                Uri downloadUri = task1.getResult();

                assert downloadUri != null;
                photoPath = downloadUri.toString();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Обычно в базе данных хранят ссылки на фотки.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант А - используйте storage, который также предоставляет firebase, а в самой базе данных храните ссылки на картинку. 
Вариант Б (из ряда костылей) - разбейте всю картинку на бинарный код и сохраняйте его в массив

Comment: Дело в том, что я храню ссылку на картинку `addUser.setMainPhoto(photoPath);`

Comment: А как на счёт того, что у вас фото возможно не успевает загрузиться в бд? Следовательно переменная не успеваем получить путь, ну и в массив не добавляется.

Comment: А вы не рассматривали возможность загружать фото, присваивая ему вместо названия id пользователя?

Comment: Спасибо за совет